# Переназначение действия кнопки

Tags: java, android, keydown

Есть приложение которое должно при нажатии на физическую кнопку переключать решим телефона с вибро на обычный и наоборот. Как переназначить нажатие, да так чтобы это дело работало после закрытия активности да ещё и при выключенном экране?

Сейчас добился чтобы это всё работало с активностью.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AudioManager am;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        am = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        AppStart();
    }

    public void AppStart() {
        if (am.getRingerMode() == RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        } else {
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NOTIFICATION)) {
            AppStart();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Overriding the hardware buttons on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543629/overriding-the-hardware-buttons-on-android)